# system not coming out of suspend

Tags: 14.04, video, suspend, gpu-driver

I have a clean 14.04 Ubuntu installation on a Dell precision T5400 with a NVIDIA card. 
The system is updated and upgraded.

When the system goes to into suspend I can see the windows of the apps I had open before the suspend. I can actually move the mouse pointer to the left and see the hide/unhide animation for the tool bar. If a plug a usb stick I can see the nautilus new window.

I can restart the desktop by restarting the lightdm process, but I loose all the windows and process I had open of course.

Does anyone have a solution or a way to debug this problem?

I created this question by accident I meant to say coming out of lock with screen turn off. The reposted question is at: [ubuntu 14.04 not coming out of lock, sometimes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459743/ubuntu-14-04-not-comming-out-of-lock-sometimes)

Comment: Perhaps you will find some hints in the log file "/var/log/pm-suspend.log" and in the "/var/log/syslog". See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Comment: Thanks, there was nothing in suspend.log, however, syslog shows that the gnome-session has a Fatal IO Error 11